# how to interpret stddev_time and hit_percent

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

I launched the following command, showed in this documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html

```
SELECT query, 
       calls, 
       total_time, 
       rows, 
       100.0 * shared_blks_hit / nullif(shared_blks_hit + shared_blks_read, 0) AS hit_percent
FROM pg_stat_statements 
ORDER BY total_time DESC 
LIMIT 5;
```

but I don't know how to interpret `stddev_time` (apparently this can show the queries that are causing problems)

And I don't understand how to interpret the following value:

```
100.0 * shared_blks_hit / nullif(shared_blks_hit + shared_blks_read, 0) AS hit_percent
```

Is it better when it's close to 0 or 100?

Answer (score 7):

`stddev_time` shows the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the execution times for this statement. If this value is close to zero, the statement has about the same execution time whenever it is run.

Large `stddev_time` values mean that the statement has widely varying run times, either because the run time varies greatly depending on the constant values or because a lot of table or index blocks are touched, and the run time depends on whether they happen to be cached or not.

The `hit_percent` this query calculates shows what percentage of the blocks needed are found in the cache. 100 is the best value, showing that only cached blocks are needed.